# Записать заголовок записи в переменную

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте!

Начал разбираться с Wordpress. 
Есть цикл Wordpress:

```
$query = new WP_Query($parameters);
if ($query->have_posts()):?>
    <h1>View posts:</h1><ol>
    <?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();?>
       <li><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" title="Link for the post: <?php the_title_attribute();?>"><?php the_title();?> </a></li>
        <?php find_image(the_title('','',false));?>     
    <?php endwhile;?>
   </ol>
<?php endif;?>
```

Помимо простого вывода, в цикле хочу вызывать функцию для работы з заголовком (find_image). Тут то и проблема: заголовок параметром не передается и выводится повторно.
Пробовал:

```
find_image(the_title('','',false));
find_image(get_the_title());
find_image(the_title());
```

Как передать?

В функции, которую я пытаюсь вызвать, должна будет по заголовку найти картинку в интернете.

`$title = the_title("","", false)` - по идее, это должно работать (как пишут на сайтах), но не работает.

Comment: Как-то странно, что вообще никаких ответов :(

Answer (score 1):

[get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) должен работать.